# Android to php (url) to sql, db shows nothing. Works in browser

Tags: java, android

I execute by new CreateNewThread().execute();

```
class CreateNewThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateThread.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Thread..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        tittel = inputTitle.getText().toString();
        tekst = inputText.getText().toString();

        if (!tittel.equals("") && !tekst.equals("")) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://.../createthread?title="
                                + tittel + "&text=" + tekst);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is,"iso-8859-1"));
                System.out.println(tittel);
                System.out.println(tekst);
                System.out.println(in);
                String line;

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(line);
                    System.out.println(jo.getString("svar"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("catchgreiene" + e);
            }

        } 
        else {
            System.out.println();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

I'm trying just to run an url. The php-file runs in browser.. This is 2.2 Froyo.
What am I missing here?

I've tried other methods, but this works for a friend. So it should work.

Comment: I've added the internet permission btw

Comment: What data you want to get? Be clear...You are unable to get 'svar' key's value? If so paste your detailed android code and php code too..

Comment: Apache stopped my access to the php-file.. just made a new one, so it works now. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's the problem, but you should NEVER do a System.out.println in android. Use Log.w("tag","key") instead!

Comment: I know, but I'm so used to it, it's only to see the strings anyway

Comment: Log.v("my tittel value: ",tittel);

Comment: System.out.println() can be used in android too.Even it is shown in logcat.. It depends on the programmer the way he likes to debug..